# Does the BreezeController support compression?

Tags: compression, breeze

Does the BreezeController have an option to enable compression? Or will I have to add a message handler myself?

See http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/aspnet-web-api-compression

Answer (score 0):

Breeze does NOT currently do anything in this area. But as per your attached link, its pretty easy to enable directly via ASP.NET.